# Putting the while condition from system input is not working

Tags: java, bufferedreader

In the `main` method I am reading the input from `system.in` and passing it to `while` condition. But it is not working. Each time it takes default 53 cases. Could not figure out where is the mistake.

If I manually assign `int num = 15` instead of `int num = br.read()` just above the while loop. It works fine.

```
public class Parenthesis
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        System.out.println("Enter number of test cases: ");
        int num = br.read();
        while(num > 0)
        {
            System.out.println(num-- + "Chances Left");
            String str = br.readLine();
            if(isParenthesis(str))
                System.out.println("Cool Rudra");
            else
                System.out.println("Poor Rudra");
        }
    }

    public static boolean isParenthesis(String str)
    {
        if(str == "Rudra")
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: try `br.readLine()`. `read()` only reads a single character as its stated in the method description. also you compare strings with `.equals()` and not with `==`

Comment: you "don't think", but i "know". see the difference?

Comment: Thank you, this worked `int num = Integer.valueOf(br.readLine())`

Comment: if you now fix the other error your program will work correctly and you will finally be "cool"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use below

```
int num = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
```

instead of

```
int num = br.read();
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to get `int`from user

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
int num = scanner.nextInt();
```